# Explicit cursors using bulk collect vs. implicit cursors: any performance issues?

Tags: oracle, for-loop, cursor

In an older article from Oracle Magazine (now online as [On Cursor FOR Loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-cursor-for-loops)) Steven Feuerstein showed an optimization for explicit `cursor for loops` using `bulk collect` (listing 4 in the online article):

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR employees_cur is SELECT * FROM employees;
  TYPE employee_tt IS TABLE OF employees_cur%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l_employees   employee_tt;
BEGIN
  OPEN employees_cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH employees_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_employees LIMIT 100;
    -- process l_employees  using pl/sql only
    EXIT WHEN employees_cur%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE employees_cur;
END;
```

I understand that `bulk collect` enhances the performance because there are less context switches between SQL and PL/SQL.

My question is about implicit `cursor for loops`:

```
BEGIN
  FOR S in (SELECT * FROM employees)
  LOOP
    -- process current record of S
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Is there a context switch in each loop for each record? Is the problem the same as with explicit cursors or is it somehow optimized "behind the scene"? Would it be better to rewrite the code using explicit cursors with bulk collect?

Comment: It rather depends on what happens at "process l_employees".

Comment: @WilliamRobertson the question is more about the differences between implicite and explicite cursors. [Pavel Smirnov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038684/2107731) provided a perfect answer to it: implicite cursors are internally optimized so there is no need to convert the implicite cursor to a manually optimized explicite one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Oracle 10g the optimizing PL/SQL compiler can automatically convert FOR LOOPs into BULK COLLECT loops with a default array size of 100.

So generally there's no need to convert implicit FOR loops into BULK COLLECT loops.

But sometimes you may want to use BULK COLLECT instead. For example, if the default array size of 100 rows per fetch does not satisfy your requirements OR if you prefer to update your data within a set.

The same question was answered by Tom Kyte. You can check it here: [Cursor FOR loops optimization in 10g](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1203923200346667188)

Comment: For the records here is the quote from Tom Kyte ["Are implicit cursor for loops optimized with an array fetch of 100? Yes"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=cursor-for-loops-optimization-in-10g#1208128100346188077)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, even if your `-- process current record of S` contains pure SQL and no PL/SQL you have context switch as the `FOR ... LOOP` is PL/SQL but the query is SQL.

Whenever possible you should prefer to process your data with single SQL statements (consider also [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606), not only DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT),  in most cases they are faster than a row-by-row processing.

Note, you will not gain any performance if you make a loop through `l_employees` and perform DLL for each record.

`LIMIT 100` is rather useless. Processing only 100 rows at once would be almost the same as processing rows one-by-one - Oracle does not run on Z80 with 64K Memory.

Comment: Thanks for the general hints on performance. However, [Pavel Smirnov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038684/2107731) provided the matching answer to my question: implicite cursors are internally optimized so there is no need to convert the implicite cursor to a manually optimized explicite one.